# enclosing all special characters in xml in cdata

Tags: cdata

i am trying to parse the xml file but getting exceptions since the file contains the special character. To make file to parse successfully i have to enclose the value in  since there are many special characters in my xml files at different places is there any way like declaration or something so that these fields will get replaced with CDATA whicch will reduce the mannual work exerytime?

Answer (score 1):

Well, either your parser is broken, or your XML.

XML has 5 predefined entities, which your parser should support, and whatever generates your XML should use them when appropiate:

```
&lt;     <
&gt;     >
&amp;    &
&apos;   '
&quot;   "
```

Comment: my file contains thousands of records mentions below:

<Employee type="contract">
        <Name>Ro&bin</Name>
        <Id>3675</Id>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>


for each time i have to check whether the records contain special character or not and if it is there i have enclose that field in CDATA mannualy so that it can parse successfully.
<Employee type="contract">
        <Name><![CDATA[Ro&bin]]></Name>
        <Id>3675</Id>
        <Age>25</Age>
    </Employee>

Is there any way to automate this mannual task?